# Is a question regarding descaling products on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I would like to ask a question about descaling products for machines (question below), but wanted to find out if it's on or off topic prior to asking as I'm new to this community. There also isn't a large enough corpus of questions having searched for scale/descaling/descaler for me to determine the answer myself.

The question I'd like to ask:

> Having recently replaced a [Gaggia Platinum Swing Up](http://www.gaggia-parts.co.uk/Gaggia-Coffee-Machines/Automatic/Gaggia-Platinum-Swing-up) with a [Sage the Oracle](http://www.sageappliances.co.uk/the-oracle.html), I have some [Gaggia Descaler](http://www.gaggia-parts.co.uk/epages/es147467.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/es147467/Products/21001682) left over.
>
> Is it possible to substitute this for the [the Descaler](http://www.sageappliances.co.uk/descaler.html) that the Sage machine uses? If so, how would I go about doing so?

*(Yes, there's a double 'the' in there. It is called 'the Descaler', presumably as the appliance it's used with is called 'the Oracle')*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a fine question to me. I'd upvote it. And we can always use more questions. ;-)

Your question is basically "can I use a different descaler product in this machine" -- right? Questions about coffee equipment and questions about cleaning are certainly on-topic, so it's totally reasonable.

See also, for example, questions tagged [equipment](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) and especially this one about [descaling espresso machines](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/242/how-does-one-descale-an-espresso-machine-and-how-often-to-do-it) but your question is certainly different enough to warrant asking.

I hope it's well-received. Some thoughts just for completeness:

- Necessary to mention your old machine? Just say you have some other leftover Gaggia brand descaler.
- Do you know the ingredients list of either descaler?
- Is your question simply "can I use the Gaggia stuff in the Sage machine?" Just another way to ask a similar question.

I hope the answer is "descalers are descalers" but analogs like "can I use off-brand ink in this inkjet printer" hopefully don't hold here.

Welcome to Coffee.SE!

Comment: P.S. Do you like the machine? :)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome :) Mention of the previous machine is me trying to ensure that every possible bit of information that may be needed is in there - in hindsight I'll drop it out of the posted question. My question is simply "Can I use the Gaggia stuff in the Sage machine" but with added garnish and hopefully the answer will be "yes".

Comment: I do like the machine, it's a very well designed piece of kit that produces (to my relatively un-cultured taste buds) a very, very good coffee.

Comment: Asked: http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/2267/1587 :)